# Why is there an independent ios-13 tag while ios-11 and ios-12 tags are mapped to the generic ios tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why is there an independent [ios-13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-13) tag while [ios-11](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-11) and [ios-12](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-12) tags are mapped to the generic [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People insist on making tags for new OS so we generally merge things down once the newness dies down. There’s little to no point to having every release have it’s own tag.

There are great reasons to have the iOS tag be monolithic.

It’s a matter of timing and in practice, almost no one ever makes a tag older than N-2 so there’s no point keeping those synonyms around.